# Integration of Modified Bessel K function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

1. Analytic result
   Integrate[x BesselK[0, x], {x, 0, x0}] gives the result of
   -1 - x0 BesselK[1, x0], for positive x0. If Let x0 = 0.001, result = -2.
2. Numerical integration
   NIntegrate[x BesselK[0, x], {x, 0, 0.001}],the result is 3.76184*10^-6

One would expect the result should be > 0. Thus, the numerical result seems to be right. Is the analytic result wrong?

Comment: "...for positive x0" implies you should use the option ``Assumptions -> x0 > 0` in `Integrate`.

Answer (score 2):

M11 seems inconsistent.

```
$Assumptions =.

Integrate[x BesselK[0, x], {x, 0, x0}]

ConditionalExpression[-x0 Subscript[K, 1](x0)-1,Re(x0)>0\[And]Im(x0)==0]

Simplify[%, x0 > 0]

-x0 BesselK[1, x0] - 1
```

Compare with

```
$Assumptions = x0 > 0

Integrate[x BesselK[0, x], {x, 0, x0}]

1 - x0 BesselK[1, x0]
```

However, M8 just works.

Comment: 10.1 has this bug too.  FWIW you only need to specify the  assumption that x0 is real to get the correct conditional expression.

Answer (score 1):

If

```
Integrate[x BesselK[0, x], x]
(* -x BesselK[1, x] *)

Limit[-x BesselK[1, x], x -> 0]
(* -1 *)
```

then `Integrate[x BesselK[0, x], {x, 0, x0}] = -x0 BesselK[1, x0] - (-1)` and

```
(-x BesselK[1, x] /. x -> 1/1000) - (-1) // N
(* 3.76184*10^-6 *)
```

Instead *Mathematica* gives:

```
Integrate[x BesselK[0, x], {x, 0, x0}]
(*  ConditionalExpression[-1 - x0 BesselK[1, x0], Re[x0] > 0 && Im[x0] == 0] *)
```

which seems incorrect.

Comment: However, `Assuming[x0 > 0, Integrate[x BesselK[0, x], {x, 0, x0}]] /. 
 x0 -> 0.001` works as expected.